# GLSL for full resolution image manipulation?

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently using GLSL shaders to render effects to live video on iOS devices. The video resolution is 640x480. When you capture a picture, the image can come in at any resolution up to 5mp. I am wondering if there is any way to apply the same GLSL shader to, for example, a 5mp texture.

Answer (score 2):

It just depends if your graphics driver/device supports that large textures and render targets. If yes, it's absolutely no problem, GLSL doesn't care about the texture or render target size.

Comment: Would you create another render target offscreen for that purpose?

Comment: @samuraisan It depends what you are doing. If you want to have the result of an effect in a texture, I would definitely use FBOs (though I have no idea if they are supported on iOS or ES in general). But if you just copy the video data into a texture and want to do a single pass effect and render its results immediately, then there's no need for FBOs and then you also don't need to care about the render target size (as the final image on screen doesn't need 5mp, which the display cannot do anyway). In this case you're quite fine, as the texture size limits tend to be less strict, I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is process the image in chunks.
Like only process a 512x512 pixel part of the image at a time.
That way you wouldn't have to care about the final image resolution (it could even be 100mp big if you have enough memory).
And as Christian Rau already pointed out: GLSL doesn't care about the size of the texture/render target.